# nginx reverse server upstream name syntax

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

**I very appreciated if someone can give me some help.
I just tried to learn the nginx reverse proxy but have experienced some problem about upstream name syntax.**

**Please refer to this photo**
[Photo: nginx reverse proxy server structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHisf.png)

When I curl 192.168.189.140, the proxy server shows

1. [debug] vhost.c(811): [client 192.168.189.140] [strict] Invalid host name 'bbs_server_pools', problem near: _serve
2. [debug] vhost.c(902): [client 192.168.189.140] Client sent malformed
   Host header: bbs_server_pools

**After I changed upstream name bbs_server_pools to bbs, it works all good.
Is this something to do with the version of nginx or something else?**

1. error Nginx.conf file

   ```
   worker_processes  1;
   error_log logs/error.log error;

   events {
   worker_connections  1024;
   }

   http {
   include       mime.types;
   default_type  application/octet-stream;
   sendfile        on;
   keepalive_timeout  65;
   log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                   '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                   '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

   server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  bbs.etiantian.org;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://bbs_server_pools;   
      } 
   }    

   upstream bbs_server_pools {
   server 192.168.189.137:80;
   server 192.168.189.138:80 weight=3;
   }  


   }
   ```
2. good nginx.conf file after changing bbs_server_pools to bbs

   ```
   worker_processes  1;
   error_log logs/error.log error;

   events {
   worker_connections  1024;
   }

   http {
   include       mime.types;
   default_type  application/octet-stream;
   sendfile        on;
   keepalive_timeout  65;
   log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                   '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                   '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

   server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  bbs.etiantian.org;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://bbs;   
      } 
   }    

   upstream bbs {
   server 192.168.189.137:80;
   server 192.168.189.138:80 weight=3;
   }  


   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with the nginx itself (well, almost nothing). It is returned by your upstream backend. The reason is that two HTTP request headers including the [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) one are always gets redefined unless some other behavior specified explicitly using the [`proxy_set_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) directive:

> By default, only two fields are redefined:
>
> ```
> proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
> proxy_set_header Connection close;
> ```

The `Host` header value of the forwarded request will be the `bbs_server_pools` with your first configuration and `bbs` with the second one. However valid characters for hostnames are ASCII letters from `a` to `z`, the digits from `0` to `9`, and the hyphen (`-`). While underscore is a valid character for the nginx upstream name, it isn't valid for the hostname, and that is the cause of the error you get from your upstream. Usually it is a good idea to keep the `Host` header value from the original request using

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

(or `$http_host`, you can check the difference [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na)). However there can be cases when you should not do it; check [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1100774/498657) answer to find out more information on this subject.

Comment: Hi Ivan! Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem altogther

Comment: The ServerFault way of thanking for the working answer is described [here](https://serverfault.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) :)